# Getting 401 with ASP.NET Core with Bearer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, unity-game-engine, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

this is my first time using ASP and doing this kind of things.

I'm trying to do a Back for a Unity proto I did with Mirror.

Right now I have the Authentification with JwtBearer (settings.Bearer is where my BearerKey is)

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(o => {
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() {
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(settings.Bearer)),
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuer = false
    };
});
```

I'm telling to use Authoritation and Authentication

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Then I have the Controller of the Auth that returns you the jwt when you login

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public IActionResult Login(AuthRequests req) {
    var (success, content) = _authService.Login(req.Username, req.Password);
    if (!success) return BadRequest(content);

    return Ok(new AuthResponse(){token = content});
}
```

And last the controller of Player itself that needs to be Authorized to use

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class PlayerController : ControllerBase {
    //...

    [HttpPost]
    public Player Register(CreatePlayerRequest req) {

        var userId = int.Parse(User.FindFirst("id").Value);
        var user = context.users.First(u => u.Id == userId);
    
        var player = new Player() {
            Name = req.Name,
            Level = 1,
            Experience = 0,
            User = user
        };
 
        context.Add(player);
        context.SaveChanges();
    
        return player;
   }
}
```

With all this when I want to access to Register of player and send on Header
**"Authorization : Bearer <key>"** it returns me a 401 Unauthorized.

I'm still new to this and been searching for a whole day but still didn't found nothing that works :(

Comment: the token you are generating, which you send to register, does that have the same signing key setup?

Comment: Yes, is the same

Answer (score 1):

found that in Core 3.0 or greatter you need

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

In this specific order

Comment: yes, was able to post that you might have to reverse your order to: app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization(); after Authentication